# VS2017 - attempts to save nuget packages into a Xamarin folder - why?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

I'm baffled by this one.

I have VS2017 (v15.9.16, updated to the latest version in mid-October 2019) installed, but for some reason, when I try to add NuGet packages to my Web project, it wants to save them into a Xamarin folder:

```
Warning MSB3106 
Assembly strong name "C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\swashbuckle.aspnetcore\4.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.dll" 
is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. 
If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(\). 
Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(\).
```

I get this Warning message 10 times in my "Error List" window.

My VS2017 project is a .Net Core 2.2 Web API solution, I have no interest in Xamarin, and have never done any Xamarin development on this laptop.  I don't know why VS2017 has decided to start using this strange path.

Where the heck is this output path set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where the heck is this output path set ?

Do you also have VS2019 in your machine? I find this issue may occur if someone is developing Xamarin in VS. I never had the path `C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\` before until I installed the Xamarin workload just now:

[image]

I guess something that comes from this workload may corrupt your nuget behavior, and that causes the wrong path in your error message.

**Suggestions:**

1.Uninstall that workload since you have no interest in **Xamarin**.

2.The direct cause of the wrong path is **Xamarin** workload places a `Xamarin.Offline.config` file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\` which sets `C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\` as one [`fallbackPackageFolders`](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-Fallback-package-folders).

Then sometimes you will get the error message with wrong path, normally the path in that kind of error message should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\` or `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\`.

So another easy way to resolve that wrong path is to delete the `Xamarin.Offline.config` in path `C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config`, that file could be the direct cause of the wrong path. (To answer your original question, this file sets that strange path for you...)

After deleting that file, [clean your nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) and delete your `obj`(where `project.assets.json` exists) folder, then the wrong path would never troubles you I think.

And for the MSB3106, you may get some help from this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490700/aspnet-core-2-0-dotnet-run-running-with-warning). Hope it helps :)

**In addition:** Check your [package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources) setting in VS, if exists the `C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\` there, delete it.

Comment: Perfect...  that was it.  Installing VS2019 seems to have buggered-up the paths for VS2017.  Removing the "Xamarin.Offline.config" file fixed the problem.... many thanks !!

Comment: Glad to know it helps :)